# Flask + Nginx proxy: Does it matter which one serves static files?

Tags: python, nginx, proxy, flask, reverse-proxy

I've got a Flask application and in front of that an nginx-server who is configured to proxy some requests to Flask.

My question is - does it matter with regards to performance whether nginx serves static files or Flask (behind the proxy from nginx)? If so, what causes the difference?

When nginx proxies to Flask - does nginx actually add any benefit with regards to caching or similar things or does it really only forward requests?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it counts.

`nginx` is written in C and handles all what shall web server handle for your static files.

Apart from speed, you will also get lower load on your Python code.

Regarding caching - if you like, `nginx` can serve for your app also as a cache, see [NGINX doc](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/caching/). But if the request is to be processed by Flask, there is nothing `nginx` would speed up apart of offloading your app by e.g. serving static files.

The extra effort for configuring `nginx` for static files might not be necessary while developing an app, but for production use I would recommend it.